# Is there a way to make Armature follows Mesh?

Tags: armature

I know that you move the mesh with the armature.

But is there a way to make the armature attach/follow the mesh when it's moved (Not by the armature but itself, the mesh)?

Thank for the answer.

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Actually if the armature is the parent of the mesh it can't be it's child. So you could make the armature the child of a mesh but it won't be its parent anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have a model that is like a serpent with an armature that has bones for the mouth and the body, and my goal is to make the serpent follow a path but since I have an armature, I can't make the serpent follow a path, it's not a simple follow a path, I need to make the serpent moves with it's curvature movement. There are many tutorials about armature follow a path but none work since I have two bone in the start/end (The mouth) of the armature and these tutorials are only for one simple armature of few bones in a line (Without bones in the middle of another bone).

Answer (score 2):

If you really need it, you can parent both mesh and armature to an empty, and then use the empty to move both (but it's more usual to leave the mesh in a 0,0,0 location in object mode, and move it using the armature controls only).

Answer (score 1):

nope obviously the armatures are done for making the mesh follow them, not the armature follow the mesh dude, there doesnt exists such of thing what are you trying to do?